# Showing a limit exists

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, limits, improper-integrals

No solution please.

I want to show that the following limit exists 
$$
\lim_{T\to \infty}\frac{1}{2T}\int_{-T}^{T}f(x)\,\overline{g(x)}\,dx
$$

where $f$ and $g$ are finite linear combinations of complex exponentials like

$f(x)=\sum_{k=1}^{N}a_{k}\mathrm{e}^{i\lambda_{k}x}$, where $x$ and $\lambda$ are real numbers.

Why calculating it isn't enough?

Thanks

Comment: Probably through the $\delta-\epsilon$ thingamajig.

Comment: By pressing tick to good answer people give you. If you don't, people are unlikely to help you in the future.

Answer (score 3):

Clearly, the product $\,f\,\overline{g}\,$ is a linear combination of functions of the form
$\mathrm{e}^{i\lambda x}$, where $\lambda$ is real. Hence, it suffices to show that, for every $\lambda\in\mathbb R$ the limit
$$
\lim_{T\to\infty}\frac{1}{2T}\int_{-T}^T \mathrm{e}^{i\lambda x}\,dx
$$
exists. If $\lambda=0$, then the above limit equals to $1$. If $\lambda\ne 0$, then 
$$
\frac{1}{2T}\int_{-T}^T \mathrm{e}^{i\lambda x}\,dx=\frac{1}{2T}\frac{1}{i\lambda}
\big(\mathrm{e}^{i\lambda T}-\mathrm{e}^{-i\lambda T}\big)=\frac{\sin(\lambda T)}{T}\to 0.
$$